# LaTeX table appears below reference, not in correct location

Tags: tables

I have a table using the `tabular` environment:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|cccccc}
& Landmarks in the Human Genome Project \\
\hline
\rowcolor{LightCyan}
1953& Watson-Crick publish DNA structure & & & & & & \\
1975& F.Sanger, A.Maxam and W.Gilbert develop methods for sequencing DNA & & & & & & \\
\rowcolor{LightCyan}
1977& Bacteriophage $\Phi X -174$ sequenced: first complete genome sequenced & & & & & & \\
1980& US Supreme court rules genetically modified bacteria are pantentable & & & & & & \\
\rowcolor{LightCyan}
1981& Human mitochondrial DNA sequenced: $16569$ base pairs & & & & & & \\
1984& Epstein-Barr virus genome sequenced: 172,281 base pairs & & & & & &\\
\rowcolor{LightCyan}
1990& International Human Genome Project launched & & & & & & \\
1991& J. Craig Venter identifies sequences of DNA complementary to messenger RNA & & & & & & \\
\rowcolor{LightCyan}
1992& Complete low resolution linkage map of the human genome & & & & & & \\
1992& \textit{Caenorhabditis} sequencing project begins & & & & & & \\
\rowcolor{LightCyan}
1992& J. Craig Venter forms the Institute for Genome Research (TIGR) & & & & & & \\
1992& Wellcome Trust and UK Medical Research Council establish The Sanger Center for large-scale genomic sequencing  & & & & & &\\
\rowcolor{LightCyan}
1995& First complete sequence of bacterial genome, \textit{Haemophilus influenzae} by TIGR & & & & & & \\
1996& High resolution map of human genome & & & & & &\\
\rowcolor{LightCyan}
1996& Completion of yeast genome, first eukaryotic genome sequence & & & & & & \\
1996& Celera claims to finish sequencing human genome by 2001, Wellcome Trust respond by increasing funding to the Sanger Center & & & & & &\\
\rowcolor{LightCyan}
1998& \textit{Caenorhabdtis elegans} genome published & & & & & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

which runs fine, and appears in the document where I want it to, however when I add one or more items to the table, the table appears at the bottom of the document below the references. Why is this? also I'm not sure how to parse LaTeX code on here to show you the table - if anyone can show me how that would be great.

Comment: Probably the reason is that the table is growing too long to fit nicely as a float in a page with text and gets put in a page dedicated to it, which is also something one would recommend from a layout point of view. You may consider using `longtables` or rearranging the contents so that they fit in a smaller space.

Comment: `}[ht]` makes it quote likely that the table goes to the end of the document use `[htp]` to give latex a chance (and add `\clearpage` before the references if you do not want floats to float past that point)

Comment: The only ways for you to show us your table are: 1) Provide a TeX code to recreate it. 2) Post an image of your table.

Comment: @David Carlisle. this worked. thanks very much

Answer (score 3):

`[ht]` makes it quote likely that the table goes to the end of the document use `[htp]` to give latex a chance (and add `\clearpage` before the references if you do not want floats to float past that point)